# "sh: 1: [MY FUNCTION]: not found " error while using os.system in python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, operating-system

throws me this error:

```
/home/gigachod/PycharmProjects/JarvisAI/venv/bin/python /home/gigachod/PycharmProjects/JarvisAI/main.py 
sh: 1: say: not found
PyCharm

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My complete code being:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os


def say(text):
    os.system(f"say {text}")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('PyCharm')
    say("Hello World")
```

I first made a virtual environment in PyCharm then pip installed the speechrecognition and pyaudio packages, I am trying to get the system to talk out whatever text I input using the "say" function.
But the os.system() function is throwing the "sh: 1: say: not found" error .

I am on pop os using a bash shell.

Please tell me where I am doing it wrong.

I tried to start and run it in bash like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lRcj.png)

got this error:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCBUI.png)

Answer (score 0):

`say` isn't a command in your computer. Assuming you're in macos, try `zsh say`.

The reason for this is that `zsh` is the shell that macos uses by default, which has all the packages that macos installs, as well as what the user installs. `sh` is a POSIX standard for all shells, and in most systems is symlinked to another shell. What shell this is for your system I can't say, but it's clear that it's not accessing your main shell, `zsh`.  You can make sure what shell you're using by running `echo $0`

Comment: No sorry forgot to mention I am on Pop Os which is  debian Ubuntu based

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details then. Do you have the `say` command installed? Run `which say`.

Comment: which say doesn't do anything. "say" is the name of the function I wrote

Comment: you are running `say` in your shell, through `os.system`. `say` isn't a command in your shell.

Comment: Please help, What should I do then? Run in a different shell?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Update your question.

Comment: I have updated my question, please help me out